# How to install Net::SSH2 from CPAN on Cygwin

Tags: windows, perl, cygwin, cpan, openssh

I needed to install `Net:SSH2` in a Cygwin environment under Windows 7 (64 bit). As usually I tried to install it with `cpanm`.

I already had the necessary Cygwin packages (see below) installed but the Perl build failed because it couldn't find the `libssh2` library.

There is a special text file [`BUILDING.WIN32`](https://metacpan.org/source/RKITOVER/Net-SSH2-0.53/BUILDING.WIN32) in the `Net::SSH2` package but this is only useful when building the module by hand and it refers mainly to MinGW. So this no help.

This is the log of the build:

```
Entering Net-SSH2-0.53
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.59 ... Yes (7.02)
Running Makefile.PL
Configuring Net-SSH2-0.53 ... Subroutine checklibs redefined at inc/Module/Install/CheckLib.pm line 11.
Subroutine assertlibs redefined at inc/Module/Install/CheckLib.pm line 25.
Subroutine _author_side redefined at inc/Module/Install/CheckLib.pm line 39.

The libssh2 library is required by this module.  If you don't have it, you can
download it from http://www.libssh2.org; you may also need OpenSSL, which can
be obtained from http://www.openssl.org , or libgcrypt, which can be obtained
from http://www.gnupg.org .

Debian:   sudo aptitude install libssh2-1-dev
OpenSUSE: sudo zypper in libssh2-1 libssh2-devel

You can pass your libssh2 lib and include dirs (and extra link args) on the
command line. E.g.:

    perl Makefile.PL lib=$HOME/libssh2/lib inc=$HOME/libssh2/include \
        ldargs="-lz"

These can also be set through the LIBSSH2_LIB/LIBSSH2_INCLUDE/LIBSSH2_LDARGS
environment variables.

To build with libgcrypt instead of OpenSSL, pass 'gcrypt' as a parameter to
Makefile.PL, e.g.:

    perl Makefile.PL gcrypt

If you want to build on Windows, see the file BUILDING.WIN32 in the
distribution.

Can't link/include C library 'ssh2', aborting.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install the `libssh2-devel` package from Cygwin, e.g. with `apt-cyg` the command line frontend for installing packages from within a cygwin shell.

```
apt-cyg install libssh2-devel
```

Then set some environment variables to the right path for getting `Net::SSH2` to work with the Cygwin packages:

```
LIBSSH2_LIB=/usr/lib/ LIBSSH2_INCLUDE=/usr/include/ cpanm -v Net::SSH2
```

That worked for me. Much easier than what the readme file linked above looked like.